# Java - is there a way to hide the close button in a swing application?

Tags: java, swing

is there a way to hide the close button in a swing application?

I know I can set `JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` but is there a way to eliminate it completely?

if I write `setUndecorated(true)` I get
`IllegalComponentStateException - the frame is displayable`

Comment: isnt there a SetVisible(false) something?

Comment: FWIW, I found this: [How to deactivate close, minimise and resizable from a window say frame?](http://www.coderanch.com/t/344419/GUI/java/deactivate-close-minimise-resizable-window) Alternatively, use a JWindow instead of a JFrame.

Comment: What about the System menu? Even if you remove the close button the user can still close the window by using Alt-F4. It's better to stick with the know solution and use "do nothing on close".

Comment: @camickr That should be done as well, yes. But it still doesn't take care of the UI, which can be very infuriating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `frame.setUndecorated(true)` while the frame has already been displayed leads to an error as this is not allowed in the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29). Instead, use `frame.setUndecorated(true)` before you set `frame.setVisible(true)`. This should solve your error:

> IllegalComponentStateException - the
>   frame is displayable

If you are successful, the close button will be hidden.

Comment: I got the same error from trying `setUndecorated(true)` after `pack()` even though I didn't use `setVisible(true)` until after.